# Tabularx with two columns and page break

Tags: longtable, tabularx

Update: Followed the xltabular manual. Works!

How can I achieve the following adjustments:

1) Control the line spacing for the table items, for example single spacing for each item, and extra space after. Something like singlespace, 6pt after, singlespace, 6pt after and so on
2) How to define fontsize only for the table items (not for the headers)?
3) How to control the left indent of the table text?

Thanks!

```
    \begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{>{\hsize=1.2\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X>{\hsize=0.8\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X}
        \caption{File endings (only for a demonstration \ldots)} \\ \hline
        .ext & Beschreibung\\\hline\endfirsthead\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\ldots\ \small cont'd}\\\hline
        .ext & Beschreibung\\\hline
        \endhead
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{2}{r@{}}{\small Continue \ldots}\\
        \endfoot
        \midrule
        \endlastfoot
        relative lange statements un Fragen in der linken Spalte &  Literatur Angaben in der Rechten Spalt \\
        bbl &  (bibliography) Hilfsdatei, enthält die Einträge für die Literatur\\
        bib &  (bibtex) enthält die Literaturdaten\\
        blg &  (bibliography log) enthält die Ausgaben eines Bib\TeX-Laufs\\
        cfg &  (config) Konfigurationsdatei\\
        aux &  (auxiliary) Hilfsdatei, enthält Querverweise usw. \\
        clo &  (class options) Definitionen für die Dokumentenklasse und die entsprechenden[...]
        Klassen-Optionen\\
        relative lange statements und Fragen in der linken Spalte &  Literaturangaben in der rechten Spalte\\
    \end{xltabular}
```

Comment: You can break tabularx tables over pages with  the `xltabular` environment, from the homonymous package. It brings the functionalities of `longtable` to `tabularx`.

Comment: I added the package, what should I add to my table code to make it work? Thanks!

Comment: Replace the `tabularx`environment with `xltabular` and use the syntax of `longtable`, in particular  `\caption` in first head and the relevant declarations before  `\endhead`,  `\endfoot`, `\endlastfoot`. That's all.

Comment: @Bernard, thanks a lot!! I adapted an example from the xltabular documentation. Above 3 new questions, do you know how to do this? Also, the package tabularx can be removed or should I keep it loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

Considering comments below your question, MWE with your table can be as follows:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, xltabular}
    \setcellgapes{3pt}
    \newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\makegapedcells
    \begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} 
                                    >{\hsize=1.2\hsize}L
                                    >{\hsize=0.8\hsize}L
                                  @{} }
\caption{File endings (only for a demonstration \ldots)} 
\label{tab:mylongtab}                                                   \\ 
    \toprule
.ext & Beschreibung                                                     \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{File endings (only for a demonstration \ldots )  (cont.)}    \\  
    \midrule
.ext & Beschreibung                                                     \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \midrule
\multicolumn{2}{r @{}}{\footnotesize Continue on the next page}
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
%
relative lange statements un Fragen in der linken Spalte 

\lipsum[1]
    &  Literatur Angaben in der Rechten Spalt                               \\
bbl &  (bibliography) Hilfsdatei, enthält die Einträge für die Literatur    \\
bib &  (bibtex) enthält die Literaturdaten                                  \\
blg &  (bibliography log) enthält die Ausgaben eines Bib\TeX-Laufs          \\
cfg &  (config) Konfigurationsdatei                                         \\
aux &  (auxiliary) Hilfsdatei, enthält Querverweise usw.                    \\
clo &  (class options) Definitionen für die Dokumentenklasse und 
        die entsprechenden [...] Klassen-Optionen                            \\
relative lange statements und Fragen in der linken Spalte 
    &  Literaturangaben in der rechten Spalte                               \\
    \end{xltabular}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
In case that you like to have tight space between rules and text and more space between rows, you can use `\addlinespace` between rows. In this case you not need the `makecell` package:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, xltabular}
    \newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
    \begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{}
                                    >{\hsize=1.2\hsize}L
                                    >{\hsize=0.8\hsize}L
                                  @{} }
\caption{File endings (only for a demonstration \ldots)}
\label{tab:mylongtab}                                                   \\
    \toprule
.ext & Beschreibung                                                     \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{File endings (only for a demonstration \ldots )  (cont.)}    \\
    \midrule
.ext & Beschreibung                                                     \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \midrule
\multicolumn{2}{r @{}}{\footnotesize Continue on the next page}
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
%
relative lange statements un Fragen in der linken Spalte

\lipsum[1]
    &  Literatur Angaben in der Rechten Spalt                               \\
    \addlinespace
bbl &  (bibliography) Hilfsdatei, enthält die Einträge für die Literatur    \\
    \addlinespace
bib &  (bibtex) enthält die Literaturdaten                                  \\
    \addlinespace
blg &  (bibliography log) enthält die Ausgaben eines Bib\TeX-Laufs          \\
    \addlinespace
cfg &  (config) Konfigurationsdatei                                         \\
    \addlinespace
aux &  (auxiliary) Hilfsdatei, enthält Querverweise usw.                    \\
    \addlinespace
clo &  (class options) Definitionen für die Dokumentenklasse und
        die entsprechenden [...] Klassen-Optionen                            \\
    \addlinespace
relative lange statements und Fragen in der linken Spalte
    &  Literaturangaben in der rechten Spalte                               \\
    \end{xltabular}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

which gives the following result:

[image]

Comment: YES! That works. I added `\setstretch{1.25}` after `\makegapedcells` because my document is setup for double line spacing. I wonder if I can control the spacing between `.ext & Beschreibung ` to `\toprule` and `\midrule` — tried `vspace{-3pt}` but that sets off the whole header. Thank you Zarko!!